# Raster Distance from each cell to nearest cell with specific value

Tags: qgis, raster, distance

To analyse the "virginity" of an area I created a binary raster with

```
1 = human infrastructure (road, housing, ...)
0 = no human infratructure (forest, agriculture, ...)
```

I would no like to calculate the distance from each cell (especially the 0-cells) to the nearest cell with value 1.

How? I use QGIS 2.18.

Comment: ok after the fifth attempt GDAL proximity did as expected...

Comment: If that has worked for you, please consider writing it as an answer yourself and accepting it, so others too may benefit from it in the future :)

Comment: thx Roberto, I answered but can't accept it yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I used GDAL Proximity Algorithm to solve the problem. Obviously I had some parameters wrong first because it's what I thought must be the way and therefore tried several times.[image: you see my working parameters here]